# Show that $(2,0,4) , (4,1,-1) , (6,7,7)$ form a right triangle

Tags: geometry, proof-verification, vectors, analytic-geometry, inner-products

What I tried:

Let $A(2,0,4)$, $B(4,1,-1)$, $C(6,7,7)$ then

$$\vec{AB}=(2,1,-5), \vec{AC}=(4,7,3), \vec{BC}=(2,6,8)$$

Then I calculated the angle between vectors:

$$\begin{aligned}
\alpha_1 &= \cos^{-1}\left(\frac{(2,1,-5)(4,7,3)}{\sqrt{2^2+1^2+(-5)^2}\sqrt{4^2+7^2+3^2}}\right) \\
&= \cos^{-1}(0)=90° \\
\alpha_2 &= \cos^{-1}\left(\frac{(4,7,3)(2,6,8)}{\sqrt{4^2+7^2+3^2}\sqrt{2^2+6^2+8^2}}\right) \\
&= \cos^{-1}\left(\frac{74}{\sqrt{74}\sqrt{104}}\right)=32.49\\
\alpha_3 &= \cos^{-1}\left(\frac{(2,6,8)(2,1,-5)}{\sqrt{2^2+6^2+8^2}\sqrt{2^2+1^2+(-5)^2}}\right) \\
&= \cos^{-1}\left(\frac{-30}{\sqrt{104}\sqrt{30}}\right)=122.5°
\end {aligned}$$

As you can see, these angles don't even form a triangle, what am I doing wrong, any thoughts?

Comment: The angle between the vectors $\vec{AB}$ and $\vec{BC}$ is actually $180$ degrees minus the angle between the _line segments_ $\bar{AB}$ and $\bar{BC}$. Draw a diagram and pay attention to which way the arrows are facing—it gives you the exterior angle, not the interior one.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

$180°-122.5°=57.5°$, and the angles sum to be $180°$, nothing wrong here.

The angles you find has nothing to do with whether there is such a triangle with the three points as vertices. The triangle is already formed by the three points before you measure the angles.

Comment: You still had to check if the three points are not on a straight line.

Comment: @DaanvdWoude isn't that done implicity by the angles not being 180°. 0° and 0° ?

Comment: Yes, but the answer states that you don't need to compute the angles, since three points always span a triangle. I just stated that this is not always the case, and that one should be careful when making this assumption.

Comment: @DaanvdWoude We don't really need to check that the three points are non-collinear. When one of the angles is already 90 degree, the three points must not be collinear.

Comment: I think you are misreading my point. You don't know that one angle is 90 degrees, according to yourself the angles do not have to measured. So then you also don't know whether or not they form a straight line.

Comment: So when you find angles in polygon like this, be aware that depending on the orientation of the vectors you use for the polygon sides, you may end up with [an exterior angle or an interior angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_and_external_angles).

Answer (score 112):

It's enough to show the following:
$$(2,1,-5)\cdot(4,7,3)=0$$
and we are done!

Comment: That is enough to prove that the angle between $\ \vec{AB}$ and $\ \vec{AC}$ is a right angle, but is it enough to prove that all all the above vectors form a triangle?

Comment: @DavidTomahak if the angle between two sides is right, it also proves that all of the points are not on the same line and thus form a valid triangle.

Comment: @DavidTomahak *Any* three points non-collinear points in space lie in a plane, and form a triangle. A B and C are clearly non-collinear, otherwise the vectors AB and AC would not be perpendicular.

Comment: Technically it is not *always* true that if $u\cdot v=0$ then $u,v$ are perpendicular.  There is also the possibility that $u=0$ (or $v=0$), but that's easy to exclude by inspection in this case.

Answer (score 66):

The distances satisfy the Pythagorean theorem.

$d(A, B) = \sqrt{2^2 + 1^2 + 5^2} = \sqrt{30}$

$d(A, C) = \sqrt{4^2 + 7^2 + 3^2} = \sqrt{74}$

$d(B, C) = \sqrt{2^2 + 6^2 + 8^2} = \sqrt{104}$

And indeed:

$\sqrt{30}^2 + \sqrt{74}^2 = \sqrt{104}^2$

Therefore it is a right triangle ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem#Converse)).

Comment: Yes, but no need to take the square root.

Comment: @WeatherVane: Not sure exactly what you mean, but Euclidean distance is defined with the square-root operator.

Comment: I meant that you don't actually need the distance, only its square - that's all.

Comment: @WeatherVane: While programmatically true, that would seem to make for a poor explanation, because the square and square roots are what people are familiar with in those definitions and theorems.

Comment: @DanielR.Collins, Sorry. I have seen those now. Your answer is correct.:-) Thanks.

Answer (score 54):

To find $\alpha_3=\angle ABC$, you should consider $\overrightarrow{BA}\cdot \overrightarrow{BC}$ instead of $\overrightarrow{AB}\cdot \overrightarrow{BC}$. That's why you have a negative cosine and obtained the supplementary angle of the correct answer.

Comment: @IntegrateThis But I think the accepted answer points out something which will be more useful in the future. That cumbersome math is sometimes useless.

Comment: @AHB This is also a better answer. OP asks "...what am I doing wrong, any thoughts?" Actually both answers together would be even better, but if it was me asking, I wouldn't be able to let go of "what am I doing wrong" before being shown the better way. Old tools sometimes turn out to be useful some other day, even after adding the shiny new tools to the sack.

Comment: @uhoh One should merge them...